# Classic ARCore-Sceneform's Augmented Image sample translation to Sceneform 1.16.0

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to translate the Sceneform 1.15.0's **Augmented Image sample** to be used with ARCore 1.18.0 and Sceneform 1.16.0. (Please note that Sceneform 1.16.0 repository at GitHub only only comes with the gltfio loader sample).

My aim is to use the GLTFIO library in order to load animated GLTFs/GLBs to show on images. (This functionality was not possible with the Android Studio plugin mechanism provided for previous versions  to Sceneform 1.16.0).

This way I change the old loading mechanism shown in the aforementioned Sceneform 1.15.0 sample:

```
...
CompletableFuture.allOf(model)
    .thenAccept((Void aVoid) -> {
        _image = image;
    
        setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()));
    
        Node nodeRenderable=new Node();
        nodeRenderable.setParent(this);
        nodeRenderable.setRenderable(modelgetNow(null));
    })
    .exceptionally(
        throwable -> {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception loading", throwable);
            return null;
        });
    }
...
```

...with something like this...

```
...
//gltfio
WeakReference<ARActivity> weakActivity = new WeakReference<>((ARActivity) _context);
//
ModelRenderable.builder()
    .setSource(_context,Uri.parse(uriAsset))
    .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
    .build()
    .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
        ARActivity activity = weakActivity.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            _image = image;
            _renderable = modelRenderable;
            //
            // Set the anchor based in the center of the image.
            setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()));
            //
            Node nodeRenderable=new Node();
            nodeRenderable.setParent(this);
            nodeRenderable.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        }
    })
    .exceptionally(throwable -> {
        Toast toast =Toast.makeText(_context, "Unable to load renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();

        return null;
    });
...
```

All run correctly, without errors nor warnings in LogCat. I mean the app tracks image perfectly but model is not shown at all.

FYI, I realized that, when I resume the app, the model is shown (but fixed to the screen) until I point the device at the (augmentable) image.

Has somebody experienced with this scenario?

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Proposed gltfio-loader code worked well. It was only a problem with the 3D model, causing that it was shown out of clipping space.